# HTML: line wrapping text

Tags: html

This image shows the result I want to achieve.
[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ8HD.jpg)

How can I add a line behind text in html email?

Answer (score 0):

Going from that image you probably want something table based (as it's an email) with a "line" cell either side of the text cell.
Depending on how exactly you want the line to look, it may be best done as an image then you have total control over it.

Something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="line.jpg" alt = "" />
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp; Recenzje &nbsp; 
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="line.jpg" alt = "" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Where the `&nbsp;` characters are forced spaces that Outlook can't ignore.